# box-item with slick slides with different background colors

Tags: css, background-color, slick.js

how can I give to 3 slick slides from a box item **different background** colors to each of them?

Now all of them have the same background color, so in **css** this is :

```
.box .box-item .box-content
{
 background:#aeaeae
}
```

Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:nth-child()` selector to target your three items.

`:nth-child(1)` will target the first child, `:nth-child(2)` the second, etc.

You can also inline your styles directly on those `<div>` elements if you don't want to write CSS rules just for these boxes. That would look like `<div style="background-color:#a00;"></div>`

Comment: Thank you very much! I tryed the both options, but I haven't the result. The color spread not into the whole box, but only as a background of the text.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the markup you are using then? If those suggestions do not work, then there is something preventing it in your markup. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve